# Flutter & Firebase: reduce the number of reads with StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a ranking page with Firebase Firestore as follows:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('user')
                            .orderBy('total_score', descending: true)
                            .limit(3)
                            .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: false),
                        builder:...
```

Everything is working almost perfectly, but I have only one problem: the number of readings is too high, I tried to limit it to 3 but it still reaches a very high number and with only 1 user.

For other pages I use cached data, which reduces the number of reads.

Is this possible in StreamBuilder? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `StatefulWidget` stream api will gets call every state changes.  Create a state variable for stream,

```dart
  late final myStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('user')
      .orderBy('total_score', descending: true)
      .limit(3)
      .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: false);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

and use it on

```dart
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
     stream: myStream
```

You can check [Fixing a common FutureBuilder and StreamBuilder problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqE-J8YJnpg&t=93s)

Comment: I'm already using StatefulWidget, the list is created only on the first startup of the page, but still the number of readings is high.

Comment: Create a state variable as I’ve included

Comment: You can check [Fixing a common FutureBuilder and StreamBuilder problem](https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg) for more

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to cache Stream data to avoid reloading on next app launch?

Comment: not sure but you might be looking for path_provider